# HttpStreamContent throws System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, httpclient

I'm currently trying to upload an image through my webservice. I have this piece of code:

```
public async Task<Webservice> editProfile(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values, byte[] image)
        {
            String strUrl = String.Format("http://********/nl/webservice/abc123/members/update");
            var HttpClientUpload = new HttpClient();
            HttpMultipartFormDataContent requestUploadContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

           Stream streamImage = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image);
            HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(streamImage.AsInputStream());

            requestUploadContent.Add(streamContent, "myFile", "image.jpg");
            foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
            {
                requestUploadContent.Add(new HttpStringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
            }

            HttpResponseMessage responseLogin = await HttpClientUpload.PostAsync(new Uri(strUrl), requestUploadContent);
            responseLogin.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (responseLogin.StatusCode == Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok && responseLogin.Content != null)
            {
                var data = new Webservice { Status = responseLogin.StatusCode };
                data.Data = await responseLogin.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(data.Data);
                return data;
            }
            return new Webservice { Status = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode() };
        }
```

But I always get the following exception: `'System.ExecutionEngineException'`  on the following line:

```
 HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(streamImage.AsInputStream());
```

Can anyone help please, struggling with this problem for days now....

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I've changed my function:

```
public async Task<Webservice> editProfile(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values, byte[] image)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = iso.OpenFile("image.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        String strUrl = String.Format("http://membr.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/abc123/members/update");

                        HttpMultipartFormDataContent requestUploadContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

                        //Stream streamImage = new System.IO.MemoryStream(stream);
                        HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());

                        requestUploadContent.Add(streamContent, "picture", "photo.jpg");
                        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
                        {
                            requestUploadContent.Add(new HttpStringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
                        }

                        HttpResponseMessage responseLogin = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(strUrl), requestUploadContent);
                        responseLogin.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        if (responseLogin.StatusCode == Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok && responseLogin.Content != null)
                        {
                            var data = new Webservice { Status = responseLogin.StatusCode };
                            data.Data = await responseLogin.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Debug.WriteLine(data.Data);
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                }     
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return new Webservice { Status = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode() };
        }
```

But now it stops in the catch part with this exception:

```
WinRT information: Response status code does not indicate success: 413 (Request Entity Too Large).
System.Exception: Request entity too large (413).
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Comment: Is there any inner exception?

Comment: Strange sometimes it  does not fail and sometimes it fails with the exception above. What do you mean with inner exception?

Comment: @StefGeelen Exceptions in .NET have an `InnerException` property. Sometimes it's null, but other times it has a value (another Exception, which itself can have its own `InnerException`) which can be critical in determining what's going on. Oftentimes an overly generic exception will explicitly tell you to check the `InnerException`.

Comment: FFS you need to capture the exception and call ToString on it in order to get all the info out of it.  The exception tells you WHAT went wrong, and good exceptions tell you WHY.  You don't seem like you've even looked at the thing except in passing.  That's not the way to go about it.  If you are debugging and you get the exception helper dialog, *there's a link at the bottom that says "copy exception details to the clipboard"*.  DO THAT.  Paste it in an [edit].

Comment: Guys, please see my edit. It works now but sometimes I get the error above...